# How to read/scan Barcode?

Tags: iphone

how can I be able to implement read/scan bar code in my iphone application. I also would like to know how to implement it into the iphone application. If possible suggest me the links and example source code and applications to understand how it works.

Comment: I'm sure you need to connect to some kind of database, code doesn't just magically know what product a barcode is linked to.

Comment: Zbar will be good to refer and implement. Also since zbar is open source you can use it without any constraints.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using the Zbar framework that is available here

http://zbar.sourceforge.net/

Check out the documentation it is well explained on how to implement it

edited: tutorial for implement Zbar: http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/tutorial.html